# Zend: how to route some action

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I have this routing

```
$router->addRoute('clinics',
 new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('clinics/:clinicPath', array('controller' => 'clinics', 'action' => 'view')),
 new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('clinics/create', array('controller' => 'clinics', 'action' => 'create1')));
```

And i want to create clinic (do the createAction) if i go 'clinics/create' and view clinic if im going something else (ex. 'clinic/happyTooth').

Now on any link rise View event. How to change this?
thx.

Comment: Have you tried putting the 'clinics/create' route first?

Comment: Yep, trying - every clinic link became 'clinics/create'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add rule on your route, try:

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('clinics/:clinicPath',
  array('controller' => 'clinics', 'action' => 'view'),
  array('clinicPath' => '(?!create)[a-z\-0-9^.]+')),
```

Comment: could you write regular expr. for example for create,delete and edit action? Thanks!

Comment: You can add | to perform OR so try (?!create|delete|edit)[a-z\-0-9^.]+

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way is to use the magic [__call](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.controller.action.html) function of the ClinicsController and do a method call matching there (and use the default route).

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `addRoute($name, $route)` properly.  You should either call it twice (once per route), or call `addRoutes(array($route1, $route2))`.  This is likely the cause of your problem.

Routes are matched in reverse order, so your order is correct.  "create" is specific, so you want it at the bottom of the list, so it is matched before the dynamic route above it.